# single dns server in a private network

Tags: dns, bind, dnsmasq, domain

I have a netgear wireless router, single web server , 100 clients with 192.168.0.0/24 network. I haven't Internet connection and I am not connected to outside world.

Now my goal is to provide the name to server's ip by installing bind& configuring in the same server. This means single server acting as DNS server & web server.

observe the scenario:

actually my server is getting the ip and every setting from the router so my server's ip always changes dynamically.In this type of situations how can i configure the "bind" in that server with dynamic ip which i am getting from router.

is this possible that the server's ip and primary dns can have same address?
if yes how the router will generate this perticular configuration to the server?.

[image]

will router assign the configuration like this to the server?

```
Ip:192.168.0.101
broadcast:192.168.0.255
Primary dns:192.168.0.101
default route:192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to tell your router to use a static assignment for the DNS server. If the DNS server's IP changes, it will break just about everything. Then, you set up BIND on the DNS server, and configure the router to send out DNS nameserver information with it's DHCP leases.

Comment: will router assign the same static ip for server's ip-address and primary dns ip-address. because my dns is running in the webserver so webserver and dns ip is same.

Comment: The static IP allocation is based on the MAC address. You can have the same IP being used for a static assignment, a DNS server, and a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Set static IP on DNS server. DHCP on router usually start from IP 100 so you have from 2 to 99 to choose.

And common sense tell to use static IP for DNS.